# Biblatex and a relational database?

Tags: biblatex, database

Is there a way of using a relation database (e.g. MySQL) as a bibsource in Biblatex?

Comment: Only with `biber` and not at the moment. Since `biber` has a modular data source interface, this isn't so hard to do. It also depends in particular about how you store names since if you are not going to store them in BibTeX format, the driver for this is more complex. I assume you mean using a database source which the user has control over rather than a specific database which has some bibliographic data in it? This latter case is inevitably very messy, as I found when adding zoterordf and endnote drivers.

Comment: Yes, you assume correcly. But the DB ought to be structured rather in the same way as a Biblatex DB, albeit in a relational manner.

Comment: I may look into this but it will take some time. If the `biber` sourcemapping feature is to work, there has to be an intermediate data layer between the SQL and the internal `biber` objects which needs a bit of thought.

Comment: Well, I haven't thought about this much I'm afraid. It is hard to do something in general here as the biber datasource drivers need to know something about the underlying relational source structure. If you have a specific database structure in mind, a driver is certainly possible.

Comment: As the comment from @PLK suggests, this is really too broad without at least some clue as to structure.